# Using Neural Networks when target variable has huge deviation

Tags: regression, neural-networks, multiple-regression

I have a dataset of **10 features** which are in the small range **between 0.5 and 1** exactly, while the target variable is between 75 and 9000 with a **standard deviation of 350**, now I need to use a Neural Network to perform regression on the data but I'm struggling with finding a suitable architecture to solve the issue I'm facing with discrepancy between the ranges of the input and output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the output layer has a linear activation function this distribution shouldn't be a problem, but you can always just rescale the target variable by dividing by 350 or 9000 (to have a SD or a maximum of 1). To obtain predictions on the original scale, you can then just multiply them.

Comment: after days of experimentation, I found that things worked best with box cox transformation on the target variable, though I'm a bit suspicious of the results they might be too good to be true